# NetSuite PHP Toolkit: Close Sales Order? (Invalid orderstatus reference key H)

Tags: php, netsuite

I'm attempting to close a Sales Order using the following code:

```
<?php
$request = new GetRequest();
$request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
$request->baseRef->internalId = $internal_id;
$request->baseRef->type = "salesOrder";
$getResponse = $service->get($request);

if (!$getResponse->readResponse->status->isSuccess) {
    $this->updateTaskStatus($task_id, 'error');
    $error = "Failed to close order, error message: ";
    $error .= print_r($getResponse->readResponse->status->statusDetail, true);

    $result = array("succeeded" => false, "error" => $error, "task_id" => $task_id, "so_id" => $internal_id);

    return $result;
} else {
    $initial_so = $getResponse->readResponse->record;

    $so = new SalesOrder();
    $so->internalId  = $internal_id;

    $so->orderStatus = SalesOrderOrderStatus::_closed;
    $so->itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();

    foreach($initial_so->itemList->item as $item) {
        $item->isClosed = true;
        $so->itemList->item[] = $item;
    }

    $so->itemList->replaceAll = false;

    $updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
    $updateRequest->record = $so;

    $updateResponse = $service->update($updateRequest);

    if(!$updateResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
        $this->updateTaskStatus($task_id, 'error');
        $error = "Failed to close order, error message: ";
        $error .= print_r($updateResponse->writeResponse->status->statusDetail, true);

        $result = array("succeeded" => false, "error" => $error, "task_id" => $task_id, "so_id" => $internal_id);

        return $result;
    } else {
        $result = array("succeeded" => true, "msg" => "Successfully closed order.");
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I initially just tried to close the sales order by updating the status but received the `Invalid orderstatus reference key H` error.

Some searching leads me to believe this was because I was not closing the items as well, so now I am closing the items by setting `$item->isClosed = true;` as shown above.

This results in the same `Invalid orderstatus reference key H` error so I'm unsure of what more is needed to close this order.

Answer (score 0):

To close sales orders you have to close them on the line level.

There is a column called closed ( id : isClosed if i can recall ) , you need to close all the lines in order to close a sales order.

Answer (score 0):

Closing all the (open) order lines is sufficient.  When all lines are closed, NetSuite automatically updates the Status.

See below from [SuiteAnswers 29086](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/29086/loc/en_US).

---

#### Scenario

A user wants to set the Status field of Sales Order to Closed using Web Services.

#### Solution

To close a Sales Order via Web Services, set the isClosed field on each of the line item to true instead of changing the orderStatus field to _closed. Do the same procedure on a User Event script.

Here is a sample Web Service request for closing a Sales Order using the isClosed field in the line item:

```
<soapenv:Body>
   <update xsi:type='platformMsgs:UpdateRequest'>
      <record xsi:type='tranSales:SalesOrder' internalId='3735'>
         <itemList xsi:type='tranSales:SalesOrderItemList'>
             <item xsi:type='tranSales:SalesOrderItem'>
                     <isClosed xsi:type='xsd:boolean'>true</isClosed>
                 <line xsi:type='xsd:long'>1</line>
             </item>
         </itemList>
      </record>
   </update>
</soapenv:Body>
```

*Note: The line field specifies the line number of the item as seen in the User Interface (always starts with 1).*

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a combination of the other answers, but specifically, you cannot set an order status to closed directly you must close each item as I do in my code. Simply removing the line from my code is enough to make it work:

```
$so->orderStatus = SalesOrderOrderStatus::_closed;
```